# Converting to str a numpy and join with pandas series

Tags: pandas, string, numpy, join, numpy-ufunc

I need help to add some random integers and some prefixed str to a pandas series. I' ll better explain:
I' ve got my pandas series called *variables* and would like to add to it random integers from 1 to 10 and also a plus and a space.
Let' s say at a given row of my pandas series I have value **x1** and I want to add (meant as join) to it the corresponding value, let's say **1**, from a generated numpy array of random numbers but also put a **space** in between and a **plus** before them.
This is what I want to obtain:

```
+1 x1
```

This is what I did:

```
import numpy as np
coeff = np.random.randint(1, 11, variables.shape[0])
coeff = coeff.astype(str)
monom = '+' + coeff + ' ' + variables
```

But it returns this error:

```
ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U11'), dtype('<U11')) -> dtype('<U11')
```

Would someone know how to help me? I' m also open in changing the way of doing it, I just need some random numbers generated but not necessarily need to pass for numpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert `coeff` into a string Series:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# dummy series for setup
variables = pd.Series(list('abcde'))

# create new random Series
coeff = pd.Series(np.random.randint(1, 11, variables.shape[0]), dtype=str)

# add
monom = '+' + coeff + ' ' + variables.astype(str)

print(monom)
```

**Output**

```
0     +8 a
1     +2 b
2    +10 c
3     +3 d
4     +8 e
dtype: string
```

As an alternative you could use the [str.cat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html) method:

```
monom = '+' + coeff.str.cat(variables.astype(str), sep=' ')
```